# Why is Commit Greyed-out in Eclipse's Egit

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, egit

The commit button in EGit has mysteriously been greyed-out.  It was working just fine a few days ago.  Does anyone know how to fix this.  I haven't found any clues on  Google.  I'd include a screenshot, but I don't have enough reputation points yet.

Comment: Have you checked permissions on the repository (especially the .git folder and it's contents)?

Comment: Had this problem before, i guess it has multiple causes, try cleaning your project or restart eclipse..

Comment: Rob - Clean didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Romain - I discovered that if I go through the "Git Repositories" view, I can commit.  So I don't think it's a permissions related problem.  Now that I figured out that I can commit using this method, this isn't nearly as big of a problem for me.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem? I ran into the same issue (see linked question).

Comment: I had the same issue after a conflict after a pull. I had my changes stashed, pulled, and then the unstash resulted in a conflict. Egit now (wrongly) wants you to commit all involved files in a single commit. So when I added all the files, it was no longer greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and found that I had unstaged changes after a remote fetch and merge. After moving the unstaged changes to Git Staging the "Commit" button was enabled.

Comment: I was panicking because I thought I broke eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem and finally managed to solve it as follows:

Since everything was working before I added the remote host, amd everything worked in my small toy project, I removed and re-added my remote host using gut bash:

git remote remove origin

git remote add origin git@my_servername:my_repository.git

After that, Egit worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try reassigning the remote origin using eclipse.If still not working, move all your files from unstaged to staging.Then the commit message will be enabled

Answer (score 0):

I my case it was because of an unresolved conflict