# EGit greying out / not showing commit

Tags: eclipse, git, pydev, egit

I've been running into a wired problem (which has been described (but not solved) [here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082322/why-is-commit-greyed-out-in-eclipses-egit):

I used to develop using PyDev and Egit (recent versions, EGit is 3.0.3) with just a local repository. Everything worked fine, I was able to commit, branch, reverse etc. just using the "Team" menue in my PyDev perspective.

Now I added a remote reposisory to host the project and since then, I can not commit to my local repository. File changes are not detected (even worse: I change file A and afterwards *all* folders are marked as "changed" (having the ">" icon) and no file is recognized as "needing synchronization". The only menu points which are available are "Add to index" (which has no effect) and "Pull" (which says "everything is up to date" - which is true since there is nothing new on the server to pull).

When I use git (either command line or git extensions), I see the changed file as changed and it's offered for staging. I can use plain git to commit, push, etc, everything works as expected and no error messages are shown. I'm just using one branch (master).

Even if I open the "Git Repository Exploring" perspective in Eclipse and got to the tab "Git Staging", the file is listed.

I jus started a new test project with just a local repository (residing in the same git-folder ~/git) and here I can commit as I'm used to... And I added the project to the same repository server - and still everthing works! I can commit, I can push, everything is fine there...

yes, I can work around hat by using git extensions, but I really liked the smooth integraion of git in eclipse. Therefore, all ideas, remarks etc. are very welcome! And yes, I tried restarting eclipse ;o).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally!!!
Since everything was working before I added the remote host, amd everything worked in my small toy project, I removed and re-added my remote host using gut bash:

`git remote remove origin`

`git remote add origin git@my_servername:my_repository.git`

I suppose some configuration files were corrupted in a very non-obvious way (I checked all config fiels and did not notice anything...)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug, and you might be able to get it back to a good state by playing around with the plugin setting data.

Located here: ${workspace}/.metadata/.plugins

I highly recommend backing up that whole folder before you start playing around. I have had other eclipse issues that have been resolved by going in here and deleting things.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I inspected every file in there containing "*git*", but found nothing suspicious.